# VLD crashing the application

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-leak-detector

ALL,

I am writing an application which apparently has memory leaks according to MSVC. This application consists of the binary executable and couple of DLLs. The application and the DLL both using "Dynamic Linking".

I also have a written application which contains only one binary file which is link statically.

I tried to apply VLD to both.

With the second application there is no problem. It can be started and is executing fine.

With the first application - I can't even start it. It is always crashing on the start-up.

I added the VLD to the mai executable and to all DLL I am producing.

So I'm wondering what might be the problem for the crash - whether it is a multiple DLL or the fact that I'm using "Dynamic Linking".

I also wonder if getting the source code of VLD and trying to compile that along with the project will help and I finally will be able to run the application and see the leaks.

Thank you for any pointers to resolve the crash.

---

EDIT1:

Here is the backtrace for the crash:

> ntdll.dll!77c40e92()
>       [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
>       vld_x86.dll!04f9abf0()
>       vld_x86.dll!04fae9df()
>       vld_x86.dll!04faeb4d()
>       KernelBase.dll!75a241e6()
>       user32.dll!75f57433()
>       user32.dll!75f55ab6()
>       user32.dll!75f558c4()
>       ntdll.dll!77c496de()
>       ntdll.dll!77c49658()
>       ntdll.dll!77c57825()
>       ntdll.dll!77c5b530()
>       ntdll.dll!77c6751f()
>       vld_x86.dll!04faf9b6()
>       vld_x86.dll!04fadd99()
>       msvcrt.dll!75c9b0f9()
>       KernelBase.dll!75a24093()
>       vld_x86.dll!04faf9b6()
>       vld_x86.dll!04faf9b6()
>       vld_x86.dll!04fade47()

Comment: What's the crash details?

Comment: Are you using modern version of VLD?

Comment: @VTT, latest and the old one. Both with the same results.

Comment: @kvr, what do you mean? When I hit "Start with debugging" it immediately crashes. MSVC log displays "Program crashes reading location <some big negative number>".

Comment: You should really provide some details, including stack trace from crash, whether it can be reproduced with hello world project, actual version of VLD and Visual Studio being used, etc. Right now this question is rather pointless.

Comment: @VTT, there is no stack trace from crash. Crash occurs somewhere in the CRT. I'm using MSVC 2010. And how do I get the VLD version? "Hello world" will probably run fine - no DLL involved, right? I guess its also possible that VLD is built statically, while my program is linking dynamically - this can create such an issue, right?

Comment: You can check VLD version by inspecting vld.dll (can be found at installation dir) version. So does hello world run fine or not?

Comment: @VTT, added the backtrace at the time of crash. The crash message reads: "Unhandled exception at 0x77c40e92 in docview.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000008."

Answer (score 1):

ALL,

I installed the latest version of VLD (2.5.1), copied the 2 dlls and the pdb to the executable directory and the program was able to start without crash.

I had some issues reading the output of VLD but I will probably create a new thread for it.

Thank you for reading and sorry for the noise.